# ValueError in submitting a form to another URL for handling

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem with submitting a form to a different URL using the form “action” attributes. 
I have a DetailView (as shown below) that shows information about a particular Teacher, like a profile page and the HTML template the DetailView renders contains a form which would be handled by another URL/view.

## views.py

```
class TeacherDetail(DetailView):
    model = Teacher
    template_name = ‘teacher_info.html’
```

## user_info.html #showing the form

```
<form method="POST" action="/inter/account/start/">{%csrf_token%}
<input type="hidden" name="teacher" id="object.id" value="{{object}}">
<button type="submit" name="invite">Invite Teacher</button>
</form>
```

My intention is to also send the object itself from this particular DetailView to the url the form would be sent to because it would be needed for the form validation.

## views.py #where the form is been sent to

```
class MakeInvitation(CreateView):
    model = Invitation
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.inviter = self.request.user.student
        form.instance.invitee = self.request.POST['teacher']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The model “Invitation” has only two fields, inviter and invitee. I made the form.instance.inviter to be the current student user and the form.instance.invitee (a ForeignKey to a Teacher model) to be the teacher whose profile page was where the form was coming from, so I am trying to use request.POST to get the object from the form in the DetailView Page.

I get a (ValueError: Cannot assign "'Test one'": "Invitation.invitee" must be a "Teacher" instance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

You're not using any of the functionality of the view or form. You should add `invitee` to the list of fields, and set the name of your hidden field appropriately. Also, the value of the field needs to be the ID of the teacher, not its string representation. So the template line is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invitee" value="{{ object.id }}
```

And the view can just be:

```
class MakeInvitation(CreateView):
    model = Invitation
    fields = ['invitee']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.inviter = self.request.user.student
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks ...but the invitee field is still not pointing to the object

Comment: Hang on, what's the relationship between teacher_info.html and user_info.html?

Comment: Sorry, the I forgot to include 'invitee' in the fields...including it fixed the problem... Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.